# Windows 8.1- How to get Dual-Band Wireless-N Adapter to work?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, wireless-networking, usb

the built-in wireless card for my Lenovo Ideapad Y410 machine is pretty weak and outdated, so I wanted to purchase a usb wireless adapter for online gaming and HD video steaming wirelessly. I was thinking of getting [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=33-124-477&SortField=0&SummaryType=0&Pagesize=10&PurchaseMark=&SelectedRating=-1&VideoOnlyMark=False&VendorMark=&IsFeedbackTab=true&Keywords=windows+8&Page=1#scrollFullInfo) product. However, i was reading in some reviews that this isn't naturally windows 8 compatible. I've heard its possible to still use it by downloading a windows 7 driver and working with that. However, I have no idea how I would go about doing that. So it would be great if anyone can help me out by giving me some step-by-step instructions on getting this wireless usb adapter to work in windows 8.1.

Thank you!

Comment: You want to game through through a USB 2 interface? If the wireless isn't bad enough, the USB isn't going to help much.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you want to find a product where the vendor supports your OS out of the box. Windows 7 has been out since 2009, and it's starting to show it's age. Windows 8 has been out for well over a year now, so there's no excuse as to why any vendor isn't releasing updated drivers for anything.

Now, with that being said, YES you can install some (not all) devices in Win8 using Win7 drivers. Yes, it does appear some users have had some luck getting this to work, how they're doing it appears to be somewhat vauge.

Most drivers (not all) are just simple packages of dlls and inf files, and while the modern GUI and new start menu of windows 8 is radically different, under the hood, it's pretty consistant with Windows 7, so getting a windows 7 driver to work in windows 8 is relatively straight forward.

Two Ideas Come to Mind...

- Running the Setup.Exe in compatability Mode
- In the Device Manager you would select update driver and then choose browse manually and just point to the old win 7 driver. It's pretty easy. You may need to extract the files from the .exe manually using WinRAR or some other application, but once you have the files extracted, again you just point to the files and away you go!